# X-tag HTML import during registration

Tags: javascript, html, import, x-tag

Is there a way to import content via an X-Tag register from an external file?

So Something like:

```
xtag.register('x-modal', {
    content: url('../modal.html');   
});
```

I know that isn't correct, but is there something similar?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you wanting to change the contents of `x-modal` dynamically, or just load a template from an html file?

Comment: Load an external file into the index.html, I ended up using an ajax call to load the files.